# How to remove the second appbar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, appbar

I am trying to build a demo chat app with `Flutter`. After my main screen, I am using `Navigator.push` to go to the details screen. 
Screenshot of problem:

[image: problem screenshot]

build method of 1st screen:

```
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text("Chat Thread App"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/settings');
          },
        )
      ],
    ),
    body: isLoading
        ? Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : new ChatThreadListCard(messageThreads: _messageThreadLists, user: _user,),
);
}
```

code of `Navigator.push` method:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => ChatDetailsScreen(threadModel: new ThreadModel(
              user.id, 
              user.fullName, 
              user.pic, 
              "otherId", 
              "otherName", 
              "otherPic", 
              post.threadId
            )
          ),
      ),);
```

build method of 2nd screen, where the problem is produced:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Chat demo"),
  ),
  body: WillPopScope(
    child: isLoading
        ? Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : Stack(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  buildChat(),
                  buildInput(),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
    onWillPop: onBackPress,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Don't nest `Scaffold`

Comment: can you please elaborate? should i not use scaffold on the second screen? if i dont use scaffold on second screen, then the back button doesnt appear.

Comment: Can you type the error I cant see the image I think imgur is banned here

Comment: the problem is, when i dont use Scaffold in second screen and navigate to it, it doesnt show the back button. and, when i use scaffold and appbar in secondscreen, there is two appbar in the second screen.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing something isn't working right with where you're setting up the `Material App`?

app.dart:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage());
  }
}
```

home_page and second_page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('First Page'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(child: RaisedButton(child: Text('Forward'), onPressed: () async {
            await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
          },)),
        ));
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => SecondPageState();
}

class SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Second Page'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Center(child: RaisedButton(child: Text('Backward'), onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },)),
        ));
  }
}
```

Which produces:

[image: Navigation Demo]

Comment: main.dart code :

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: 'Chat apps Demo',
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => SplashScreen(),
        '/login': (context) => LoginScreen(),
        '/home' : (context) => ChatThreadScreen(),
        '/settings' : (context) => SettingScreen(),
      }));
}

after that: 
if(isLoggedin){
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/home");
        }else{
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/login");
        }

Comment: sorry not sure how would i add new line there. heres pastebin link [link](https://pastebin.com/2v8zjn10)

Answer (score 2):

the problem turns out to be, i was creating a MaterialApp widget in scaffold's body. so, when the onTap method was called, the new screen was replaced insdie the MaterialApp's area. didnt replace the whole screen.

the trick was to remove the `return new MaterialApp()`.

thanks everyone.